# How to do UI automation in Oracle IDE with Groovy?

Tags: oracle, swing, groovy

I am using ODI 12c. According to the documentation, I should be able to import swing libraries using Groovy and click on menu items.

I have tried the sample code, and it works fine. For example, I am able to click on «File» using «doClick» by importing javax.swing.JMenuItem, getMenuBar() and getGUI()

However, how do I automate clicks on elements in my project? I.e. expanding a folder or double clicking on a project object.

The following code will click on "file":

```
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

import javax.swing.JMenu;

import oracle.ide.Ide;


test = ((JMenuItem)Ide.getMenubar().getGUI(false).getComponent(0));


println(test.getName())

test.doClick();
```

This is how the IDE looks. How do I for example generate a click to expand folder "Backup"?

[Screenshot of IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBRHj.png)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.